# How can I retrieve a real position of row after filter?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table with a filter.
If I use this code to select the row that I clicked before add a filter it retrieve incorrect index:

```
handleRowPress : function(evt){

        var selectedRowNum = evt.getSource().indexOfItem(evt.getParameter("listItem"));
        ...

    },
```

For example if I have 5 results A B C D E and after filter I have C and E, whith previous code if I click on E, selectedRowNum is 2, but I want 5!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want that? The result of method `indexOfItem` is just that: the index of the row in the current (filtered) table, not the index of the object in the underlying model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the binding context path of your selected list item and then get the index of the row.

```
var itemContextPath = evt.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContextPath();

var indexOfRow = parseInt(itemContextPath.substring(itemContextPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1, itemContextPath.length));
```

Regards,
Allen

Comment: it works! Where did you find a solution? I can't find nothing in the documentation